# Type Mismatch in Listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have created a user form and in there I have placed a listbox and 2 text boxes.

Now my query is when I select a item then the items some characters to be display in both textboxes, when I try to do this I get a error msg for Type mismatch please correct me

```
Option Explicit
Dim a() As String
Dim b() As String
Dim i As Long

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
a = Split("meter, inch, foot, yard", ",")
b = Split("m, In, Ft, Yd", ",")
For i = 1 To ListBox1.ListCount

If ListBox1.Value(i, 0) = a(i) Then
   TextBox1.Value(i, 0) = b(i) And TextBox2.Value(i, 0) = b(i)
End If
Next
End Sub
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
a = Split("meter, inch, foot, yard", ",")
ListBox1.List = a
End Sub
```

Thanking you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to accomplish but you could try something like the following. just add the events for MouseClick or SelectedIndexChanged from your ListBox to ListBox1_Click. I would prefer the second. And the onFormLoad of your Form to ListBox1_Click. if you insert my code snippet into an empty project you can check out if it works they way you want it.

Sry but it's a little hard to predict what you want to accomplish (:

Anyway there are still cleaner solutions for this problem using databindings. If you are interested let me know. But Databindings are more complex I would say ..

Here is the code

```
Public Class Form1

Dim a() As String = Split("meter, inch, foot, yard", ",")
Dim b() As String = Split("m, In, Ft, Yd", ",")

Private Sub ListBox1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseClick

    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
        TextBox2.Text = String.Empty
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = a(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
        TextBox2.Text = b(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub onFormLoad(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(a)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for Your quick response i am using office 2007 and the code for Excel file VBA format i thnik by mistakenly the code stored in VB.net.  When i copy and paste the code then it is not work  Kindly excuse me and give the correct code for that

Comment: Hello kindly help me on this issue